# Opening 2nd maven project always closes the 1st project in intellji

Tags: intellij-idea

1. Preferences/Apperance/system settings,

   "Open project in the same window" is selected
2. open the 1st project
3. goto File/open, to open the pom file from 2nd project,

   open as project

this always closes 1st project, only 2nd project exists in intellij.

How to make both projects exist in the intellij-idea pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this and it seems to be working now:

Step 1: Open the 1st project (from pom.xml)

Step 2: Add your modules
There are several ways of adding modules. Any of them are fine. I find the fastest for repeated adds is:

File > Project Structure > Modules
Click “+”
Choose “Import module”
Navigate to the build file (ex pom.xml) or .iml file for generic projects

Answer (score 0):

In Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings there is an  option "Open Project". Choose "New Window".

Comment: Not sure, that would have 2 instances of intellij running, i just to have 1 intellij with 2 separate projects.